# How to insert DropDownList selected value to GridView in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

namespace NewDPOcopy
{
    public partial class UpdatePaperCost : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       Services.ServiceAuthentication ser = new Services.ServiceAuthentication();
       // Services.ServiceAuthentication ser = new Services.ServiceAuthentication();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillgrodPaperType();
            ddlcatid.Visible = true;
            ddlcatid.DataSource = ser.Getpapercategory();
            ddlcatid.DataTextField = "Cat_Name";
            //ddlcatid.DataValueField = "Cat_id";
            ddlcatid.DataBind();
        }

        protected void fillgrodPaperType()
        {
            Services.PaperTypes[] PaperInfo = ser.GetALLPaperTypeInfo();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_id", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_weight", typeof(int)));

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_size", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_cost_per_sheet", typeof(double)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_status", typeof(string)));


            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_used_by_247", typeof(Boolean)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_front_finish", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_back_finish", typeof(string)));

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_default", typeof(Boolean)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_colour", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_nexpress", typeof(Boolean)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pt_igen", typeof(Boolean)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cat_Name", typeof(string)));

            for (int i = 0; i < PaperInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = null;
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["pt_id"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_id;
                dr["pt_name"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_name;
                dr["pt_weight"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_weight;

                dr["pt_size"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_size;
                dr["pt_cost_per_sheet"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_cost_per_sheet;
                // dr["pt_cost_per_sheet"] = 12;
                dr["pt_status"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_status;

                dr["pt_used_by_247"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_used_by_247;
                dr["pt_front_finish"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_front_finish;
                dr["pt_back_finish"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_back_finish;

                dr["pt_default"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_default;
                dr["pt_colour"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_colour;
                dr["pt_nexpress"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_nexpress;
                dr["pt_igen"] = PaperInfo[i].Pt_igen;
                dr["Cat_Name"] = PaperInfo[i].Cat_Id;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            GrdvwPTID.DataSource = dt;
            GrdvwPTID.DataBind();

            //ddlPTID.DataSource = dt;
            //ddlPTID.DataTextField = "pt_name";
            //ddlPTID.DataValueField = "pt_id";
            //ddlPTID.DataBind();
        }    

        protected void ClearPaperType()
        {
            txtptid.Text = "";
            txtptname.Text = "";
            txtptweight.Text = "";
            txtptsize.Text = "";
            txtptcostpersheet.Text = "";
            txtptstatus.Text = "";
            txtptfontfinish.Text = "";
            txtptbackfinish.Text = "";
            txtptcolor.Text = "";
            ddlptdefault.ClearSelection();
            ddlptdefault.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
            ddlptnexpress.ClearSelection();
            ddlptnexpress.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
            ddlptusedby247.ClearSelection();
            ddlptusedby247.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
            ddlptigen.ClearSelection();
            ddlptigen.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
            lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = false;
            HiddenField2.Value = "";
        }

        protected void GrdvwPTID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        protected void GrdvwPTID_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {    
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            Session["INDEX"] = index;

            lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = false;

            txtptid.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
            txtptname.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
            txtptweight.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
            txtptsize.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text;
            txtptcostpersheet.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text;
            txtptstatus.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[6].Text;

            ddlptusedby247.ClearSelection();
            if (GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[7].Text == "True")
            {
                ddlptusedby247.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ddlptusedby247.Items.FindByText("No").Selected = true;
            }

            txtptfontfinish.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[8].Text;
            txtptbackfinish.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[9].Text;
            ddlptdefault.ClearSelection();
            if (GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[10].Text == "True")
            {
                ddlptdefault.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ddlptdefault.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = false;
            }
            txtptcolor.Text = GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[11].Text;

            ddlptnexpress.ClearSelection();
            if (GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[12].Text == "True")
            {
                ddlptnexpress.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ddlptnexpress.Items.FindByText("No").Selected = true;
            }
            ddlptigen.ClearSelection();
            if (GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[13].Text == "True")
            {
                ddlptigen.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ddlptigen.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = false;
            }
            //ddlcatid.ClearSelection();
            //if (GrdvwPTID.Rows[index].Cells[14].Text == "True")
            //{
            //    ddlcatid.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = true;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    ddlcatid.Items.FindByText("Yes").Selected = false;
            //}
            HiddenField2.Value = "EditPAPERTYPE";    
        }

        protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtptid.Text == "" || txtptname.Text == "" || txtptweight.Text == "" || txtptsize.Text == "" || txtptcostpersheet.Text == "" || txtptstatus.Text == "" || txtptfontfinish.Text == "" || txtptbackfinish.Text == "" || txtptcolor.Text == "" || ddlptdefault.SelectedItem.ToString() == "<--select-->" || ddlptnexpress.SelectedItem.ToString() == "<--select-->" || ddlptusedby247.SelectedItem.ToString() == "<--select-->" || ddlptigen.SelectedItem.ToString() == "<--select-->")
            {
                lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = true;
                lblMessagePTYPE.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblMessagePTYPE.Text = "FILL ALL THE FIELDS AND CLICK HERE TO SUBMIT";    
            }
            else
            {    
                Boolean ptused247;

                if (ddlptusedby247.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Yes")
                {
                    ptused247 = true;
                }
                else
                {

                    ptused247 = false;
                }

                Boolean ptDefault;

                if (ddlptdefault.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Yes")
                {
                    ptDefault = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ptDefault = false;
                }

                Boolean ptNexPRESS;

                if (ddlptnexpress.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Yes")
                {
                    ptNexPRESS = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ptNexPRESS = false;
                }

                Boolean ptIgen;

                if (ddlptigen.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Yes")
                {
                    ptIgen = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ptIgen = false;
                }   

                Boolean catName;

                if (ddlcatid.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Yes")
                {
                    catName = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    catName = false;
                }
                //insert Query Call...........

                if (HiddenField2.Value != "EditPAPERTYPE")
                {
                    bool InsertResultPT = ser.InsertPaperType(txtptid.Text, txtptname.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtptweight.Text), txtptsize.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtptcostpersheet.Text), txtptstatus.Text, ptused247, txtptfontfinish.Text, txtptbackfinish.Text, ptDefault, txtptcolor.Text, ptNexPRESS, ptIgen, catName);
                    if (InsertResultPT)
                    {
                        lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = true;
                        lblMessagePTYPE.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        lblMessagePTYPE.Text = "PAPER TYPE VALUES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY!";
                        fillgrodPaperType();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = true;
                        lblMessagePTYPE.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        lblMessagePTYPE.Text = "YOU ENTERED WRONG VALUES !";
                    }

                    // ClearPaperType();
                    txtptid.Text = "";
                    txtptname.Text = "";
                    txtptweight.Text = "";
                    txtptsize.Text = "";
                    txtptcostpersheet.Text = "";
                    txtptstatus.Text = "";
                    txtptfontfinish.Text = "";
                    txtptbackfinish.Text = "";
                    txtptcolor.Text = "";
                    ddlptdefault.ClearSelection();
                    ddlptdefault.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                    ddlptnexpress.ClearSelection();
                    ddlptnexpress.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                    ddlptusedby247.ClearSelection();
                    ddlptusedby247.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                    ddlptigen.ClearSelection();
                    ddlptigen.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                    HiddenField2.Value = "";
                }    
                else
                {
                    //Update Query Call...........
                    bool UpdateResult = ser.UpdatePaperTypes(txtptid.Text, txtptname.Text, Convert.ToInt16(txtptweight.Text), txtptsize.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtptcostpersheet.Text), txtptstatus.Text, ptused247, txtptfontfinish.Text, txtptbackfinish.Text, ptDefault, txtptcolor.Text, ptNexPRESS, ptIgen,catName);
                    if (UpdateResult)
                    {
                        lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = true;
                        lblMessagePTYPE.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        lblMessagePTYPE.Text = "PAPER TYPE VALUES UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY!";
                        fillgrodPaperType();
                        txtptid.Text = "";
                        txtptname.Text = "";
                        txtptweight.Text = "";
                        txtptsize.Text = "";
                        txtptcostpersheet.Text = "";
                        txtptstatus.Text = "";
                        txtptfontfinish.Text = "";
                        txtptbackfinish.Text = "";
                        txtptcolor.Text = "";
                        ddlptdefault.ClearSelection();
                        ddlptdefault.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                        ddlptnexpress.ClearSelection();
                        ddlptnexpress.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                        ddlptusedby247.ClearSelection();
                        ddlptusedby247.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                        ddlptigen.ClearSelection();
                        ddlptigen.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                        HiddenField2.Value = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = true;
                        lblMessagePTYPE.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        lblMessagePTYPE.Text = "Updation failed please try again.";    
                    }

                    HiddenField2.Value = "";
                }    
            }

            txtptid.Text = "";
            txtptname.Text = "";
            txtptweight.Text = "";
            txtptsize.Text = "";
            txtptcostpersheet.Text = "";
            txtptstatus.Text = "";
            txtptfontfinish.Text = "";
            txtptbackfinish.Text = "";
            txtptcolor.Text = "";
            ddlptdefault.ClearSelection();
            ddlptdefault.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
            ddlptnexpress.ClearSelection();
            ddlptnexpress.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
            ddlptusedby247.ClearSelection();
            ddlptusedby247.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
            ddlptigen.ClearSelection();
            ddlptigen.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
            HiddenField2.Value = "";
        }

        protected void btndelete_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HiddenField2.Value != "EditPAPERTYPE")
            {    
                lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = true;
                lblMessagePTYPE.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblMessagePTYPE.Text = "PLEASE SELECT THE RECORD FROM TABLE!";
            }
            else
            {    
                bool deletePaperType = ser.RemovePaperType(GrdvwPTID.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(Session["INDEX"].ToString())].Cells[1].Text);

                if (deletePaperType)
                {
                    lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = true;
                    lblMessagePTYPE.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblMessagePTYPE.Text = "PAPER TYPE VALUES HAS BEEN DELETED SUCCESSFULLY!";
                    HiddenField2.Value = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessagePTYPE.Visible = true;
                    lblMessagePTYPE.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblMessagePTYPE.Text = "No match found !";
                    HiddenField2.Value = "";
                }
                // ClearPaperType();
                txtptid.Text = "";
                txtptname.Text = "";
                txtptweight.Text = "";
                txtptsize.Text = "";
                txtptcostpersheet.Text = "";
                txtptstatus.Text = "";
                txtptfontfinish.Text = "";
                txtptbackfinish.Text = "";
                txtptcolor.Text = "";
                ddlptdefault.ClearSelection();
                ddlptdefault.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                ddlptnexpress.ClearSelection();
                ddlptnexpress.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                ddlptusedby247.ClearSelection();
                ddlptusedby247.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                ddlptigen.ClearSelection();
                ddlptigen.Items.FindByText("<--select-->").Selected = true;
                fillgrodPaperType();    
            }    
        }

        protected void btncancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearPaperType();
        }
    }
}
```

I have the above code in that in Page_lode event its binding the value to dropedown but when i am going to insert but its not inserting and not showing into grideview but in dropedown all values are binded how to insert into grideview? and  dr["Cat_Name"] = PaperInfo[i].Cat_Id; is null only its not taking values but in my db cat_id values are there.

Comment: Have you tried Gridview autogenerate columns=true and the Bind directly the datatable to griview source ??

Comment: you still need to set Autogenerate Columns= true for GrdvwPTID as @Dot_NETJunior suggested. Otherwise you would have to set up the displaying columns in the markup.

Comment: See - right now you only define the datasource of the gridview. But the Gridview doesn't know which Data it should display because you didn't set it up in Markup. To automatically display all Columns of your Datatable you just add `GrdvwPTID.AutoGenerateColumns = true;` in your page_load event

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friend. But I have seen your code improper manner, heard to understand. 
But what I have understand that, you are binding gridview first, for that you are calling method **ser.GetALLPaperTypeInfo();** 
please check what **PaperInfo[i].Cat_Id;** is returning. **Cat_ID** or **Cat_Name** ?
second you have to provide **ddlcatid.DataValueField** as well while biding in page lode event. 
you should provide **ser.InsertPaperType()** method here. want to see what exactly error throwing while inserting? 
you are inserting Cat_Name as a **boolean** but while binding grid view your are defining  **dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cat_Name", typeof(string)));**

please provide proper code and specific only.

Comment: i have GetALLPaperTypeInfo() service here i am getting the cat_name value but " dr["cat_name"] = PaperInfo[i].Cat_name;" here its showing null

Comment: did you set gridview property AutoGenerateColumns="False"? if yes then make it as true. else make all  **<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cat Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="Cat_Name">**. set same for all DataField attribute for BoundField in .aspx page for GrdvwPTID. Or if you are getting **dr["Cat_Name"] = PaperInfo[i].Cat_Id;** is null while debugging please check the **GetALLPaperTypeInfo()** method whether its returning value or not for **PaperInfo[i].Cat_Id;**.

Comment: k but id i selct value from dropedown list it will not select default value its taking how to do?

Comment: You mean  dropedown list is not taking selected value? That's why i told you set ddlcatid.DataValueField; and make **<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcatid" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">** :- AutoPostBack="true" ddlcatid.DataSource = ser.Getpapercategory();
            ddlcatid.DataTextField = "Cat_Name";
            ddlcatid.DataValueField = "Cat_id";

Comment: In **ser.Getpapercategory();** method get Cat_Name and Cat_id value. then whenever you will select any value from dropdown text will change and you will get [ddlcatid.DataTextField= selected text and ddlcatid.DataValueField= selected text value.]

Comment: ya i amselecting and storing in variable but its not coming in properly

Comment: why you are storing in variable? while inserting you can get directly from ddlcatid. what you want to store in database 'True/False' or value (1/0)? could you please provide me Getpapercategory Cat_Name and Cat_Id getting from database? make dr["Cat_Name"] = PaperInfo[i].Cat_Id; to dr["Cat_Name"] = PaperInfo[i].Cat_Name;

Comment: ddlcatid this dropedown contians silk,matta,gloss,other these are the list

Comment: you made lots of confusion. I have seen that you are binding ddlcatid with (silk,matta,gloss,other) suppose value are (1,2,3,4). When you will bind dropdown text will be silk and value will be 1 correct? But in **protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)** you are checking **if (ddlcatid.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Yes")**. what you are trying to do here. you are storing  catName = true; or catName = false; then what is the connection of that ddlcatid?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to bind the gridview on the btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) event of the button rather than page load and make sure autogeneratecolumns is set to true/false according to your requirement .